# Retrieving all records asynchronously then performing an action

Tags: node.js, mongodb

In a node.js server, using the mongodb native driver, I want to retrieve records from a cursor and then output them as JSON. I have this (simplified)

```
var ans = {ids: []};
cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
 if (doc) {
  ans.ids.push(doc.tag);
 }
});
cursor.count(function(err, result) {
 ans.count = result;
 res.send(JSON.stringify(ans));
});
```

and the result is something like `{ids:[], count: 3}`. In other words the query *appears* to run without returning any records. I assume that this is because the data's already been sent before the `cursor.each` callbacks have run. How do I re-structure this to make sure the sending happens after the iterating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer. The example for [cursor.each](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#each) says "If the item is null then the cursor is exhausted/empty and closed", so: (error handling omitted)

```
var ans = {ids: []};
cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
 if (doc) {
  ans.ids.push(doc.tag);
 }
 else {
  cursor.count(function(err, result) {
   ans.count = result;
   res.send(JSON.stringify(ans));
  });
 }
});
```

Comment: Yes, the documentation of this is buried in the example code of the `cursor.each` [docs](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#each).

Comment: You can accept this as the answer even though you posted it yourself to make it clear it's complete.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I have updated the answer and linked to the cursor.each docs.